# laravel relationship associate Call to undefined method

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've had this working before in a controller but now can't get it working in a repository set up.

I have two models - books and ticketAudit as below.

I'm trying to associate ticketAudit to books but I get an error Call to undefined method

Here are my models:

**Book Model:**

```
class Book extends Eloquent {
    public function ticketAudit() {
    return $this->hasMany('TicketAudit');
}
}
```

**TicketAudit Model:**

```
class TicketAudit extends Eloquent {
    public function book() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Book');
}
}
```

In book controller I have the following (book is injected):

```
public function store()

{
    $input = Input::all();

    $result = $this->book->create($input);

    if ($result) {
    //     //if book created then create tickets

         $this->ticket->createTicket($input, $result);

         return Redirect::route('books.index');
    }
}
```

and in the method createTicket in the repository I have:

```
public function createTicket($input, $book) {

    $counter = $input['start_number'];

    while($counter <= $input['end_number']) {

        $ticketDetails = array(
            'ticketnumber'=>$counter,
            'status'=>'unused',
            'active'=>1
            );

        $newTicket = $this->ticket->create($ticketDetails);

        $newTicket->associate($book);

        $newTicket->save();


        $counter = $counter+1;

    }
    return $counter;
}
```

the associate method is causing the error - I've got this working in other models but this change to a repository is causing me headaches!

What error have I made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make all of this much shorter:

```php
public function createTicket ($input, $book) {

    $counter = $input['start_number'];
    $end     = $input['end_number'];

    for ( ; $counter <= $end; $counter++ )
    {
        $book->ticketAudit()->save($this->ticket->newInstance(array(
            'ticketnumber' => $counter,
            'status'       => 'unused',
            'active'       => 1
        )));
    }
}
```

Comment: Great - thank you. I get cautious with chaining methods as not always clear to me which order etc. Thanks for your help